# Modify dict in dataframe cell

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I've got a pandas data frame. In every cell there is a dict:

```
id | A                | B              | ...
1  | {"a": 1, "b":1}  |{"d": 1, "e":1} | ...
2  | {"a": 2, "b":3}  |{"d": 5, "e":6} | ...
...
10  | {"a": 1, "b":1}  |{"d": 1, "e":3} | ...
```

I'd like to update one cell (e.i 1,A ):

```
df.loc[1,"A"].update({"c":2})
```

This procedure updates every single cell which has the same dict, so in this case there would be (1,A  and 10,A would be changed):

```
id | A                       
1  | {"a": 1, "b":1, "c":2}  
2  | {"a": 2, "b":3}         
...
10  | {"a": 1, "b":1, "c":2}
```

How can I force python to update **only** 1,A?

This is how I create data frame:

```
df = pd.read_csv( file_path, sep='\t', names=['id', 'A'], compression='gzip', converters={1:ast.literal_eval})
```

Comment: sounds like you have views of dictionaries stored all over your dataframe. So if you change one, you change all the others. Maybe do a test to see if 1,A and 10, A are the same object

Comment: to add to @Yuca 's comment, you should think of a column of dicts as a column of pointers to dicts (and what you observe would happen if two rows have the same pointer-value)

Comment: Any ideas how can I construct df to avoid the issue? @Yuca

Comment: honestly I don't have experience with that. You seem to have a very clean construction so my first guess would be to check if there's a parameter for `read_csv` that helps

Comment: @IanS To be honest, operating on pointers is not my intension. They have made themselves spontaneous...

Comment: For me it working nice, but in python 3.6. Can you try `cols = ['A','B']`
`df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(ast.literal_eval)` instead `converters={1:ast.literal_eval}` ?

Comment: @ruan, Yuca is suggesting that you try `df.loc[1,"A"] is df.loc[10,"A"]` to see if they're the same (or similarly see if `id(df.loc[1,"A"])` and `id(df.loc[10,"A"])` are the same)

Comment: @jezrael - nothing changed

Comment: @ruan - So still same problem? One thing - are dictionaries necessary?

Comment: @IanS - IDs are the same;/ That's the problem - but I really don'y know why;/

Comment: @jezrael - still the same;( Seems that's impossible. It would be really nice to use dicts in my case

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

As identified in the comments, both dictionaries in `[1, "A"]` and `[10, "A"]` are the same, so you cannot update one without updating the other.

While I don't understand why this happens, deep-copying the dictionary in each cell solves the problem:

```
import copy
df = df.applymap(lambda d: copy.deepcopy(d))
```